# Decoupling a QStateMachine from the UI

Tags: qt, architecture, state-machine

I made this post on the Qt Forum as well but I haven't gotten any follow up so I'm hoping to continue the discussion some here. Here is the relevant parts of my post and the response.

My Post:

> I have the following design: A main window which has a widget, and
> inside that widget different widgets of type "Page" can be loaded. The
> first page, let's call it the startup page, allows the user to type in
> the serial number of the product. The database is then queried to get
> some info about the product itself, and then a concrete child class
> representing the type of "Product" is created. All child product
> classes inherit from an abstract class, Product.
>
> Basically, when the user selects the product by entering a serial
> number, a product factory is called to create the concrete object and
> then check if it's physically connected to the system via a bus. This
> created product will then be passed to and used by other pages in
> somewhat of a wizard like fashion.

Response:

> The biggest problem I see [...] is that the ui
> is kinda driving your logic. Typically that's a bad idea and down the
> line leads to problems that are hard to foresee in the planning stage.
>
> The way I would approach it is that your app is a state machine.
> There's user input stage, product lookup stage (which may fail from
> what you describe), product view/editing stage etc. Transitions
> between those stages would dictate a ui change, for example switching
> from product id input to product lookup would switch ui page from
> input form to a wait indicator and finishing the query would move
> either to success or fail state, which would show an error page or the
> product page accordingly. The product object would then be governed by
> the state machine state that handles it. Lookup would produce an
> object and pass it to the view/edit state and that state would free it
> when transitioning to another state. Your logic would be better
> encapsulated this way and independent of the ui, which you may want to
> change someday or make optional e.g. drive the state machine in a
> silent mode, app params or something else. The ui would just send a
> signal that would change the machine state e.g. entering a number
> would transition the machine from input to lookup, which in turn could
> be connected to page change.

The issue I'm having here is I'm not seeing how this actually decouples my application logic from my UI? The QStateMachine would be configured to transition between states based on button clicks which is inherently coupling it to my UI. If I wanted some type of "headless" mode, I'd basically have to reconfigure my entire state machine to attach to signals from different objects. I suppose I could try to abstract this by having a builder type class that configures all the state transitions based on what mode I'm in.

Maybe this indicates I would need some sort of intermediate object which is used whether or not I have a UI, and the state machine connects to signals from that object instead. My different widgets would then contain a reference to this same object and utilize it.

Basically, I am asking how I can decouple my state machine from the UI when it seems it's coupled by design, since what's driving the state machine is the UI itself.

Answer (score 0):

The QStateMachine class and its related classes are not coupled “by design” to the UI. They could be used to implement state machines in any layer of the app.

The response you received just advocates for a better separation of concerns.

Like you already said (about the “headless” mode), you can pack your business logic in a component that drives such a state machine to handle the flow of your process. You can of course have also other state machines, in the UI, to handle model updates, user interaction and page navigation.